# \SIlist does not work though there is no problem with \SIrange

Tags: siunitx

When trying to compile the following I get the error undefined control sequence `\SIlist`. Other parts of the `siunitx` package like `\SIrange` work perfectly well, so I really have no idea what what I am doing wrong here. I would really appreciate your help since I love this package and want to use it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SIlist{1;3}{\mole}
\SI{1}{ppm}
\SIrange{10}{30}{\metre}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably just need to update you `siunitx` package.  Works fine for me with an updated TL 2012.

Comment: The latest version is `2.5j`.

Comment: Your example runs without error for me, perhaps you need to update some packages?

Comment: I use the package `texlive-science`, `siunitx` is a part of it. I just uninstalled it an installed it again with my packet manager. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Add `\listfiles` _before_ `\begin{document}` and see what version of `siunitx` that is reported. Mine is `siunitx.sty    2012/09/18 v2.5j`.

Comment: If you're using TeXlive 2009, [AskUbuntu how to upgrade to 2012.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012)